# Can I catch updates to members of an observable struct in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observable

I have a struct that is defined in a COM library.
In my ViewModel I have created an observable instance of this, and want to bind each member of the struct to different controls in a view.
ConfigStaticDataDetails variable is updated through a delegate in the COM.

Is there a way to catch updates to the members of the struct so that my view reflects the update?

Part of the struct:

```
public struct ConfigStaticData
{
    public string Callsign;
}
```

My: variable:

```
private ConfigStaticData _ConfigStaticDataDetails;
public ConfigStaticData ConfigStaticDataDetails
{
    get
    {
        return _ConfigStaticDataDetails;
    }
    set
    {
        _ConfigStaticDataDetails = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ConfigStaticDataDetails");
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```xml
<TextBox Name="ConfigStaticDataCallsignLabelTxt"
         Margin="0,2,0,2"
         Width="230"
         Style="{DynamicResource EditableTextBox}"
         Text="{Binding Source=ConfigStaticDataDetails, Path=Callsign}" />
```

I have tried different ways, but this my current code (which doesn't work).

Comment: You cannot bind to fields, and the source as you specified it is interpreted as a string. You might want to take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should replace that struct with a class of your own, only using the struct for portability. Structs should be immutable; as such, there is rarely anything interesting to observe. And due to value semantics, each observer might be seeing a different value (or maybe boxed object). Structs and events don't mix well...

Comment: What's "elrarwly" supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably write some code in a Binding Converter to facilitate the notification. to make it more portable, you can wrap the "notify" logic in a extension  method related to your struct

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inputs.
I think my solution will be to redesign the COM interface, and use classes implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface instead of structs. This seems to work as expected.